# Conditional (if)

Tags: grammar, conditionals, spoken-english

1. Nowadays, countless websites will only function if you **open** an account, which means providing them with an email address and some of your personal data.
2. Nowadays, countless websites will only function if you **opened** an account, which means providing them with an email address and some of your personal data.

Version 1 is the corrected sentence. I'm still not totally convinced whether 2 could be acceptable.

Comment: 2. would be OK if you replaced "will" with "would". "... countless websites would only function if you opened an account,

Comment: Thank you. That would be a conditional two then. So let me ask in another way. Is the "opened" version unsalvageable wrong or not?

Comment: Both are a mess. The second one is a bigger mess. This looks like a universal statement. Get rid of *will* and use infinitives. The tenses of *open* and *provide* should synch in time.

Comment: @Nederlanditis No: 2. is not acceptable. In a remote conditional, if you use preterite "would" in the protasis, you must use preterite "opened" in the apodosis. The open conditional 1. is fine, though, where present tense "will" matches present tense "open".

Comment: @PhilSweet - is synching open and provide a style advise or a strictly grammatical issue? Or in other words: is it wrong or only a bit odd?

Comment: You can change your time point of view at will. Changing tenses when referring to an established event will shift the viewpoint, not the event's chronology. But there isn't any reason to do so here. And there are restrictions on when this is felicitous. See here - [Purdue Owl](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/verb_tenses/verb_tense_consistency.html)

Comment: I disagree with the last comment. Conditionals require the tense of the verb in the protasis and that of the verb in the apodosis to match, i.e. preterite "would+opened" in remote conditionals, and present tense "will+open" in open conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatical and idiomatic.

I hesitate to call the second ungrammatical, but it is certainly not idiomatic.

What would be an idiomatic alternative is

> Nowadays, countless websites work ony if you have opened an account.